# Comparing two ways of calculating an algebraic set

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Disclaimer: My knowledge of algebraic geometry is bounded by 15.1 of Dummit and Foote. If any of what I wrote here is incorrect please let me know!!

Consider the equation $0=-1+x+z+xyz$ over a field $F$.

We can find all the solutions to this equation by examining three different cases:

$(1a):$ $x=0 \rightarrow z=1,y \in F$

$(2a):$ $z=0 \rightarrow x=1, y \in F$

$(3a):$ $z \neq 0 \neq x \rightarrow y = (1-x-z)(x^{-1}z^{-1})$, so in this case we have that $x,z \in F^{\times}$

Thus, as a set, the solutions to this equation is $F \amalg F \amalg (F^{\times})^2$.

We can also say that $\operatorname{Spec} \frac{F[x,y,z]}{(-1+x+z+xyz)}$ is equal to the closed subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^3$ given by:

$V(f - 1) = \{ (x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \mathbb{A}^3 : x + z + xyz = 1 \}$. This subvariety is not disconnected, the sequence $(x,y,z)=(\frac{1}{n},0,1-\frac{1}{n})$
is a sequence of solutions of case (3) but whos limit is in case (1).

---

Now, here is another way to get a a full set of solutions to the equation $0=-1+x+z+xyz$:

$(1b)$
Suppose we have a solution $(x,y,z)=(d,e,f)$ to the equation $xyz=1$. Then the triple $(x,y,z) = (-d,d^{-1}-e,e^{-1}-f)$ is a solution to the equation in question:

$0 = -1 - d+e^{-1}-f+(-d)(d^{-1}-e)(e^{-1}-f)$

$= -1 - d + e^{-1} - f - e^{-1} + f + d - def$

$= -1-def = 0$

$(2b)$ $(x,y,z) = (1,-1,-f)$ where $f \in F$ is a solution:

$$0 = -1 + 1 + (-f) + (1)(-1)(-f)$$

$(3b)$ $(x,y,z) = (0,-e,1)$ where $e \in F$ is a solution:

$$-1 + 0 + 1 + (0)(-e)(1) = 0$$

It is clear that these solutions, as a set, is also equal to $F \amalg F \amalg (F^{\times})^2$

Can somebody help me understand what is going on here? Are the solutions to each of these cases somehow in bijective correspondence with each other on a topological level? On a set level? Is there any relationship between them at all? I'm sorry if my question is poorly worded, in truth, I'm looking for any insight into this situation what-so-ever.

Thank you for your time, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Please don't delete your [(prior) queston](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3907682/242) and repost it anew when you make edits. Instead simply edit the original question (which had no answers or comments yet, so edits would not conflict with anything)

Comment: Okay... Sorry about that!!! I felt like I added enough and had more thoughts that I wanted to post it a-new and fresh, but now that I look it was unnecessary.